# what will happen when you give session timeout is -1 in java?

Tags: java, session

```
 <webapp> ...   
     <session-config>
         <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>    
     </session-config> 
 </webapp>
```

what will happen when you give session timeout is -1.

Comment: Read the documentation

Answer (score 2):

With numeric values a negative value (although most commonly given as just `-1`) often means `unlimited` in cases where a negative value wouldn't make any sense logically, such as timeouts or sizes etc.

Comment: can you answer it more clearly! you mean session never expired?

Comment: @karunkumar battula Yes, session will never expire